# Search for string in many WBs and post results into another WB

Tags: beginner, vba, excel

I want to search for a string inserted in `TextBox1` on `Mainwb` within a range of data located in Workbook `officerA` Worksheet `DATA!(A2,G2000)`, and then paste results found into Workbook `Mainwb.sheet("MAIN SCREEN").Range (A5,G500)`

I am totally new to VBA and wrote this code quoting from many sources. I'd like to know how it can be improved.

This is used to search within the same workbook:

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim wb1 As Workbook, Wb2 As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim strSearch As String
Dim f As Variant
Dim fAddress As String
Dim fRow As Long
Dim cellA As Variant
Dim cellB As Variant


 Set Wb2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\elhayani\Desktop\development\AML db\OfficerA.xlsx") 
  Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\elhayani\Desktop\development\AML db\Mainwb.xlsm")
   Set ws2 = wb1.Sheets("MAIN SCREEN").Range("A5:G2000")
   Set ws1 = Wb2.Worksheets("DATA")  

strSearch = TextBox1.Value

ws1.Range("A5:G2000").ClearContents
Set dmr = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\aselhayani\Desktop\Excel Reports\OfficerA.xlsx")
Set dmr = Worksheets("DATA")
strSearch = InputBox("Please enter T24 ID:", "Search Value")

pasteRowIndex = 5

If strSearch = vbNullString Then
    MsgBox ("User canceled, or did not enter a value.")
    Exit Sub
End If

With ws1.Range("A2:G2000")

    Set f = .Find(strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not f Is Nothing Then
        fAddress = f.Address
        Do
            fRow = f.Row
            cellA = ws2.Cells(fRow, 1).Value
            cellB = ws2.Cells(fRow, 2).Value
            cellC = ws2.Cells(fRow, 3).Value
            cellD = ws2.Cells(fRow, 4).Value
            cellE = ws2.Cells(fRow, 5).Value
            cellF = ws2.Cells(fRow, 6).Value
            cellG = ws2.Cells(fRow, 7).Value

            ws1.Cells(pasteRowIndex, 1) = cellA
            ws1.Cells(pasteRowIndex, 2) = cellB
            ws1.Cells(pasteRowIndex, 3) = cellC
            ws1.Cells(pasteRowIndex, 4) = cellD
            ws1.Cells(pasteRowIndex, 5) = cellE
            ws1.Cells(pasteRowIndex, 6) = cellF
            ws1.Cells(pasteRowIndex, 7) = cellG

            pasteRowIndex = pasteRowIndex + 1

            Set f = .FindNext(f)

        Loop While Not f Is Nothing And f.Address <> fAddress
    End If
End With
MsgBox "Search Done"
End Sub
```

Comment: This code appears to be broken - the description says it is searching for the value from `TextBox1.Value`, but that value is never used - it's overwritten on the line `strSearch = InputBox("Please enter T24 ID:", "Search Value")`.

Comment: @Comintern IMO, that seems like an overly harsh interpretation, considering the code does actually "work" and the OP is quite obviously a beginner here. Would be better to clarify which value they want to search for and/or why they're asking for it in 2 different places.

Comment: totally agree I am new in coding :) . I am searching for client number  and I am asking for it in  2 or more different workbooks cause Client might be served or linked to client which served by one employee and each employee extract his reports into separate excel sheets

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! It looks like you have a good question here. Did you come from another language or did you learn by using the macro recorder?

Comment: No totally new to coding and learning from this site and YouTube

Answer (score 3):

#### Variables

Good job is making sure to declare all variables with a *type*:

```
 Dim wb1 As Workbook, Wb2 As Workbook
```

However, there's no real reason to group your variables like that; as you see with your strings it would get too long.

More on variables - give them some meaningful names. And avoid that [hungarian naming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation):

```
Dim sourceWorkbook As Workbook
Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook
Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
Dim searchValue As String
Dim foundAddress As String
Dim foundRow As Long
Dim searchArray As Variant
```

Oh no, you didn't declare these variables:

```
  cellA = ws2.Cells(fRow, 1).Value
  cellB = ws2.Cells(fRow, 2).Value
  cellC = ws2.Cells(fRow, 3).Value
  cellD = ws2.Cells(fRow, 4).Value
  cellE = ws2.Cells(fRow, 5).Value
  cellF = ws2.Cells(fRow, 6).Value
  cellG = ws2.Cells(fRow, 7).Value
```

Why not use a range or an array? Seems like it will always be columns 1:7. Something like

```
For Each f In searchRange 'or your specific range
    Set f = searchRange.Find(searchValue, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not f Is Nothing And f.Address <> fAddress Then
        ws1.Range(Cells(pasterowindex, 1), (Cells(pasterowindex, 7))) = ws2.Range(Cells(fRow, 1), (Cells(fRow, 7)))
    End If
Next
```

But with better variables. I also dislike `Do` loops and stick to `For Each` loops, but that's my preference. It also can avoid the `With` block - you're nesting too many things, I think.

You also missed declaring these: `dmr, pasteRowIndex`

But I don't see you ever actually using `dmr`?

When you don't define your variable, VBA will declare it as a *Variant*, which are [objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcxd6b8.aspx):

> Performance. A variable you declare with the Object type is flexible
>   enough to contain a reference to any object. However, when you invoke
>   a method or property on such a variable, you always incur late binding
>   (at run time). To force early binding (at compile time) and better
>   performance, declare the variable with a specific class name, or cast
>   it to the specific data type.

By not declaring variables, you could possibly be paying a penalty.

Always turn on `Option Explicit`. You can have it automatically by going to Tools -> Options in the VBE and checking the **Require Variable Declaration** option. This way if you have any variables not defined, the compiler will let you know.

Additionally, I have no way of telling what `dmr` is. Plus first it's a `workbook` and then it's a `range` - the only reason it's working is because you didn't declare it and it's inherently a `variant`. Get two variables with good names in there!

Plus, what's this?

```
dim ws2 as worksheet
Set ws2 = wb1.Sheets("MAIN SCREEN").Range("A5:G2000")
```

Setting a `worksheet` variable to a `range`? Also why does `ws2` reference `wb1` and vice-versa? I got really confused on what the source and target actually are.

---

#### Praise

- *Great job* using `vbNullString` instead of `" "`.
- Good job using a `Long` instead of `Integer`. Integers - [integers are obsolete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409117/why-use-integer-instead-of-long/26409520#26409520). According to [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa164506(v=office.10).aspx) VBA *silently* converts all integers to `long`.
- Good job following [Standard VBA naming conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1s46s4ew(v=vs.140).aspx)

---

#### Misc

When you do this

```
 ws1.Range("A5:G2000").ClearContents
```

You already gave the book and sheet a variable, just give this a `range` variable - it will make the code look cleaner. Additionally if you're using `2000` because you don't know how big the range is, 
there is a [standard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11169920/1161309) way to find lastRow and lastColumn. That post explains why.

What is this spacing about -

```
 Set Wb2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\elhayani\Desktop\development\AML db\OfficerA.xlsx")
  Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\elhayani\Desktop\development\AML db\Mainwb.xlsm")
   Set ws2 = wb1.Sheets("MAIN SCREEN").Range("A5:G2000")
   Set ws1 = Wb2.Worksheets("DATA")
```

Be sure you align your levels:

```
Set Wb2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\elhayani\Desktop\development\AML db\OfficerA.xlsx")
Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\elhayani\Desktop\development\AML db\Mainwb.xlsm")
Set ws2 = wb1.Sheets("MAIN SCREEN").Range("A5:G2000")
Set ws1 = Wb2.Worksheets("DATA")
```

Also, what happens if the book isn't found or the sheet doesn't exist? Handle those errors!

Same goes for a space in the inputbox - `" " <> vbNullString`

Also why are you doing this -

```
strSearch = TextBox1.Value
...
strSearch = InputBox("Please enter T24 ID:", "Search Value")
```

I don't see that `TextBox1` ever being used.

---

#### My version

Would look *something* like this -

```
Option Explicit

Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim sourceWorkbook As Workbook
Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook
Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
Dim sourceRange As Range
Dim targetRange As Range
Dim searchCell As Range
Dim searchValue As String
Dim targetRow As Long
targetRow = 5
Dim lastRow As Long

On Error GoTo ErrHandler

Set sourceWorkbook = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\elhayani\Desktop\development\AML db\OfficerA.xlsx")
Set sourceSheet = sourceWorkbook.Worksheets("DATA")
lastRow = sourceSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set sourceRange = sourceSheet.Range("A5:G" & lastRow)

Set targetWorkbook = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\elhayani\Desktop\development\AML db\Mainwb.xlsm")
Set targetSheet = targetWorkbook.Sheets("MAIN SCREEN")
Set targetRange = targetSheet.Range("A5:G" & lastRow)
targetRange.ClearContents

searchValue = InputBox("Please enter T24 ID:", "Search Value")
If searchValue = vbNullString Or searchValue = " " Then Exit Sub

For Each searchCell In sourceRange 'or your specific range
    Set searchCell = sourceRange.Find(searchValue, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not searchCell Is Nothing Then
        targetSheet.Range(Cells(targetRow, 1), (Cells(targetRow, 7))) = sourceSheet.Range(Cells(searchCell.Row, 1), (Cells(searchCell.Row, 7)))
        targetRow = targetRow + 1
    End If
Next
Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    MsgBox "WHOOPS"

End Sub
```

---

#### Advanced

Your way of doing the loop to `.Find` the search value is pretty complicated considering you can just **[.FindNext](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/) and avoid the loop altogether**, but I know that's a lot to take in right now.

Answer (score 2):

I'm starting from an excerpt of your written specifications:

*"I want to search for a string ... within a range of data located in Workbook officerA Worksheet DATA!(A2,G2000), and then paste results found into Workbook Mainwb.sheet("MAIN SCREEN").Range (A5,G500)"*

to which I'm adding:

- what can be derived from part of your code:

  *"Previous results in "MAIN SCREEN" (from row 5 downwards) must be erased"*
- what I guess it could (or should?) be:

  *"search must be made in column "A" of "DATA" worksheet"*

With all what above stated, let's start:

---

**Range reference errors**

in your `With ws1.Range("A2:G2000")` block you're:

- looking for `strSearch` in `ws1`, i.e. in "DATA" worksheet of "OfficerA" workbook, with:

  `Set f = .Find(strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues)`

  and that's OK with *specifications*
- writing `ws2` data into `ws1` worksheet, with all those:

  ```
  cellA = ws2.Cells(fRow, 1).Value
  ...
  ws1.Cells(pasteRowIndex, 1) = cellA
  ```

  i.e. you're writing "MAIN SCREEN" worksheet of "Mainwb" workbook data into "DATA" worksheet of "OfficerA" workbook

  and that's **NOT OK** since *specifications* says the opposite:

  *"paste results found into Workbook Mainwb.sheet("MAIN SCREEN").Range (A5,G500)"*
- using `fRow` as the row index for *source* cells in `ws2`

  `fRow = f.Row`
  `cellA = ws2.Cells(fRow, 1).Value` '<-- `fRow` is used as row index of `Cells` object in `ws2`

  which once again is **NOT OK**, since `fRow` is the index of the found cell in `ws1`, and has therefore no logic connection with `ws2`

---

**Determination of a worksheet last non empty row**

your `ws2.Range("A5:G2000").ClearContents` seems much a *hard coded* way to *embrace* a sufficiently wide range where previous data could reside and delete them

but things can grow beyond initial expectations and cause problems

furthermore acting on a wider range than the actually necessary one could arise performance issues

so it should always be determined the *actual extension* of the wanted range

this can be done in different ways, depending on your data structure

for instance should all "DATA" worksheet be cleared, than you could use

```
ws2.UsedRange.ClearContents
```

which would clear the content of all cells between the most up-left *used* cell and the most bottom-right one. (here, the *used* term has a very wide meaning: check for it in msdn documentation)

or, should all cells belonging to a well defined column range be cleared, then you could use

```
Intersect(ws2.UsedRange, ws2.Columns("A:G").ClearContents
```

where you act on the `Range` resulting from the *intersection* of the `ws2` wanted columns and its `UsedRange` (determined as above explained)

still, there could be the need to act on cells belonging to certain columns but not above a specific row (like your case could seem to be)

in this case a good coding habit of doing this is the following:

```
With ws '<--| reference a worksheet
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row '<--| get referenced worksheet last non emtpt cell row in its column "A"
    If lastRow > 4 Then .Range("A5:G" & lastRow).ClearContents '<-- clear columns A:G cells from row 5 down to column "A" last non empty one
End With
```

here it's assumed that column "A" is the *counter* one, i.e. any "non empty" row has at least column A cell filled with some value

---

**`Find()` method has "memory"**

When using [Find()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx) method you'd better always explicitly specify its `LookIn`, `LookAt`, `SearchOrder`, and `MatchByte` parameters. should they be not specified then settings from its last call (even form Excel UI one!) would be used.

So you want to use:

```
Set f = .Find(what:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
```

Moreover your actual searching range is `Range("A2:G2000")`, which means all cells from row 2 to 2000 in columns A to G, while it's quite probable you want to look in one column only

I'll assume column "A" a the *searching* one

---

**Pasting Values**

you're writing unnecessary code lines, since every single *couple* of statements:

```
cellA = ws2.Cells(fRow, 1).Value
...
ws1.Cells(pasteRowIndex, 1) = cellA
```

can be shortened down to:

```
ws1.Cells(pasteRowIndex, 1).Value = ws2.Cells(fRow, 1).Value
```

but you can have them all shortened down to a single statement like:

```
Range1.Value = Range2.Value
```

provided both ranges have the same size, which in your case could be achieved as follows:

```
ws2.Cells(pasteRowIndex, 1).Resize(, 7).Value = ws1.Cells(fRow, 1).Resize(, 7).Value
```

with both `ws1` and `ws2` defined as per your original code (i.e. not yet *swapped* for what above discussed in "Variable names consistency" section)

---

**Miscellanea**

- put any *exit* condition at the top of your module, to avoid unnecessary execution of code lines

  Sub CommandButton1_Click()
      Dim strSearch As String

  ```
  strSearch = TextBox1.Value

  If strSearch = vbNullString Then
      MsgBox ("User canceled, or did not enter a value.")
      Exit Sub
  End If

  '... rest of the code
  ```
- Variable names consistency

  you can adopt whatever naming convention you may want, but you must be consistent with it throughout your code so as to make your code more readable and thus more *debuggable* and finally more maintainable.

  that's why since "MAIN SCREEN" is a `wb1` workbook worksheet, you should set it to some `ws1` worksheet variable instead of `ws2` to which should be set any worksheet belonging to `wb2` workbook instead:

  ```
  Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("MAIN SCREEN").Range("A5:G2000")
  Set ws2 = Wb2.Worksheets("DATA")
  ```

---

**SUMMARY #1**

for all what above your code could become the following:

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim strSearch As String

    strSearch = TextBox1.Value

    If strSearch = vbNullString Then
        MsgBox ("User canceled, or did not enter a value.")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet, ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim f As Range
    Dim fAddress As String, lastRow As Long, fRow As Long, pasteRowIndex As Long

    Set Wb2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\elhayani\Desktop\development\AML db\OfficerA.xlsx")
    Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\elhayani\Desktop\development\AML db\Mainwb.xlsm")

    Set ws1 = wb1.Worksheets("MAIN SCREEN")
    Set ws2 = wb2.Worksheets("DATA")

    With ws1 '<--| reference "destination" worksheet
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row '<--| get reference worksheet last non emtpty cell row in its column "A"
        If lastRow > 4 Then .Range("A5:G" & lastRow).ClearContents '<-- clear only cells from row 5 down to colmun "A" last non empty one
    End With

    With ws2 '<--| reference "source" worksheet
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row '<--| get reference worksheet last non emtpty cell row in its column "A"
    End With

    pasteRowIndex = 5
    With ws2.Range("A2:A" & lastRow) '<--| reference "searching" column in "source" worksheet
        Set f = .Find(what:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
        If Not f Is Nothing Then
            fAddress = f.Address
            Do
                fRow = f.Row
                ws1.Cells(pasteRowIndex, 1).Resize(, 7).Value = ws2.Cells(fRow, 1).Resize(, 7).Value
                pasteRowIndex = pasteRowIndex + 1
                Set f = .FindNext(f)
            Loop While Not f Is Nothing And f.Address <> fAddress
        End If
    End With
    MsgBox "Search Done"
End Sub
```

---

**BOOST IT UP!**

but you can both shorten your code and speed it up by exploiting the following features

---

**Autofilter**

[Autofilter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193884.aspx) method of `Range` object allows for selection of multiple rows out of a range by filtering on given columns matches

for instance, with:

```
With ws1
    With .Range("A1:G" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
        .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=TextBox1.Value
```

you first reference a `ws1` worksheet range delimited by columns A to G and row 1 to column "A" last non empty cell row, and then filter it on its first column to match `TextBox1.Value`

after it you either get filtered cells or not, so which you may check for it as follows:

```
If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells.Resize(, 1)) > 1 Then
```

where you count the number of visible cells of first columns and ask them to be greater than one since the header one gets always filtered

should any cells be filtered then you can reference them all in one shot by use of [`SpecialCells`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157.aspx) method of `Range` object, specifying `xlCellTypeVisible` as its `Type` parameter

```
rng.Offset(1).Resize(rng.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

where once again you skip header cells by means of `Offset()` and `Resize()` methods of `Range` object

---

**Use `With...End With` to decrease variables number **

finally you can avoid the use of many variables by means of `With ... End With` blocks in a proper order

for instance:

```
With Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\elhayani\Desktop\development\AML db\Mainwb.xlsm").Sheets("MAIN SCREEN")
```

allows for both the opening the specified workbook and referencing its "MAIN SCREEN" worksheet

---

**SUMMARY #2**

a possible resulting *final* code can be the following:

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim destRng As Range

    If Me.TextBox1.Value = vbNullString Then
        MsgBox ("please enter a value")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\elhayani\Desktop\development\AML db\Mainwb.xlsm").Sheets("MAIN SCREEN") '<-- open "destination" workbook and reference its "MAIN SCREEN" worksheet
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row '<--| evaluate its column "A" last non empty cell row
        If lastRow > 4 Then .Range("A5:G" & lastRow).ClearContents '<--| clear possible old data from row 5 downwards
        Set destRng = .Range("A5:G5") '<--| set the "destination" range
    End With

    With Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\elhayani\Desktop\development\AML db\Mainwb.xlsm").Worksheets("DATA") '<--| '<-- open "source" workbook and reference its "DATA" worksheet
        With .Range("A1:G" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row) '<--| reference its range in columns A:G from row 1 to column "A" last non empty cell row
            .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=TextBox1.Value '<--| filter range on its 1st column with TextBoxx value
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells.Resize(, 1)) > 1 Then '<--| if any cell other than header ones has been filtered...
                .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy destRng '<--|...copy all filtered values (skipping headers) to destination range
            End If
            .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False '<--| show all rows back
        End With
    End With

    MsgBox "Search Done"
End Sub
```